# How to send parameter while calling the method using ksoap parsing in android

Tags: android, android-intent, ksoap2

I am doing soap based parsing .I am able to get get response when there is no parameter in method .But Now I am calling function which having some parameter and returning a object.While trying I am getting null.I am call this function **getDestinationStationDashboard** and parameter is **"HNH"**

Here is my code .

```
package com.example.soapbased;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Soapclass extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://wsendpoints.bbrailapps.firstgroup.com/getDestinationStationDashboard";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getDestinationStationDashboard";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://wsendpoints.bbrailapps.firstgroup.com";
    private static final String URL = "http://railapps.firstgroup.com/FirstGroupRailApps/services/RailAppsCAWS?wsdl";
    private SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_soapclass);
        System.out.println("=====================" + haveNetworkConnection());

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object>() {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Soapclass.this);
            private PropertyInfo pi1;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog.show();
            };

            protected Object doInBackground(Void[] params) {

                /*resultRequestSOAP = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envp.dotNet = true;
                envp.setOutputSoapObject(resultRequestSOAP);
                AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(
                        URL);
                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
                    SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envp.getResponse();
                    System.out.println("resultsString"+resultsString);
                    return resultsString.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("---------------------------"+e.toString());
 Log.d("ppp", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(Soapclass.this,
                            "Check Network connectivety" + e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v("WS Error->", e.toString());
                    return e.toString();
                }*/

                 resultRequestSOAP = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                 pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
                 pi1.setName("crsCode");
                 pi1.setValue("HNH");//get the string that is to be sent to the web service
                 pi1.setType(String.class);
                 resultRequestSOAP.addProperty(pi1);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envp.dotNet = true;
                envp.setOutputSoapObject(resultRequestSOAP);
                AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(
                        URL);
                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
                    SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envp.getResponse();
                    System.out.println("resultsString"+resultsString);
                    return resultsString;

                } catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("---------------------------"+e.toString());
 Log.d("ppp", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(Soapclass.this,
                            "Check Network connectivety" + e.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v("WS Error->", e.toString());
                    return e.toString();
                }


            };

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Soapclass.this,
                        "Check Network connectivety" + result,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            };
        }.execute();

    }

    public boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }

}
```

After change I am getting this object 
I am getting this    SoapObject obj = (SoapObject)envp.getResponse(); 
                    System.out.println("resultsString"+obj);

```
resultsStringanyType{RID=201309201377618; alertDetailPopulated=true; alertsId=0; alertsSummary=anyType{}; destExpArrival=06:31; destSchArrival=06:30; destinationStation=anyType{crsCode=BKJ; stationName=Beckenham Junction; }; expArrival=06:19; expDepart=06:20; otherAlertPresent=false; platformNo=3; routeDetailPopulated=false; routeDetails=null; rsID=null; schArrival=06:19; schDepart=06:19; serviceAlertPresent=false; toc=SE; tocName=Southeastern; trainID=2M06; trainLastReportedAt=null; }
```

Now how to print RID or something else from this object.

Comment: SoapObject obj = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://wsendpoints.bbrailapps.firstgroup.com/getDestinationStationDashboard";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getDestinationStationDashboard";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://wsendpoints.bbrailapps.firstgroup.com";
    private static final String API_URL = "http://railapps.firstgroup.com/FirstGroupRailApps/services/RailAppsCAWS?wsdl";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new DownloadSoap().execute();
    }

    private void doNetwork() {
        SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi1.setName("crsCode");
        pi1.setValue("HNH");
        pi1.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        resultRequestSOAP.addProperty(pi1);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = true;
        try {
            envp.setOutputSoapObject(resultRequestSOAP);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(API_URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
            System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envp.getResponse();
            System.out.println("resultsString" + response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class DownloadSoap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Fetching Data");
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            doNetwork();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

**Its working for me, but it taking so much of time to fetch the data.**

**I am getting Response like below:-**

```
09-20 12:22:39.974: I/System.out(2421): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><getDestinationStationDashboardResponse 
xmlns="http://wsendpoints.bbrailapps.firstgroup.com"><getDestinationStationDashboardReturn><RID>201309201377851</RID><alertDetailPopulated>false</alertDetailPopulated>
<alertsId>0</alertsId><alertsSummary xsi:nil="true"/><destExpArrival>08:15</destExpArrival><destSchArrival>08:15</destSchArrival><destinationStation><crsCode>BKJ</crsCode>
<stationName>Beckenham Junction</stationName></destinationStation><expArrival>08:04</expArrival><expDepart>08:04</expDepart><otherAlertPresent>false</otherAlertPresent>
<platformNo>3</platformNo><routeDetailPopulated>false</routeDetailPopulated><routeDetails xsi:nil="true"/><rsID xsi:nil="true"/><schArrival>08:04</schArrival><schDepart>08:04</schDepart>
<serviceAlertPresent>false</serviceAlertPresent><toc>SE</toc><tocName>Southeastern</tocName><trainID>2M20</trainID><trainLastReportedAt xsi:nil="true"/></getDestinationStationDashboardReturn>
<getDestinationStationDashboardReturn><RID>201309201377886</RID><alertDetailPopulated>false</alertDetailPopulated><alertsId>0</alertsId><alertsSummary xsi:nil="true"/>
<destExpArrival>08:30</destExpArrival><destSchArrival>08:30</destSchArrival><destinationStation><crsCode>BKJ</crsCode><stationName>Beckenham Junction</stationName>
</destinationStation><expArrival>08:19</expArrival><expDepart>08:19</expDepart><otherAlertPresent>false</otherAlertPresent><platformNo>3</platformNo>
<routeDetailPopulated>false</routeDetailPopulated><routeDetails xsi:nil="true"/><rsID xsi:nil="true"/><schArrival>08:19</schArrival><schDepart>08:19</schDepart>
<serviceAlertPresent>false</serviceAlertPresent><toc>SE</toc><tocName>Southeastern</tocName><trainID>2M22</trainID><trainLastReportedAt xsi:nil="true"/>
</getDestinationStationDashboardReturn><getDestinationStationDashboardReturn><RID>201309201377085</RID><alertDetailPopulated>false</alertDetailPopulated>
<alertsId>0</alertsId><alertsSummary xsi:nil="true"/><destExpArrival>09:38</destExpArrival><destSchArrival>09:38</destSchArrival><destinationStation>
<crsCode>BDM</crsCode><stationName>Bedford</stationName></destinationStation><expArrival>08:12</expArrival><expDepart>08:13</expDepart>
<otherAlertPresent>false</otherAlertPresent><platformNo>2</platformNo><routeDetailPopulated>false</routeDetailPopulated><routeDetails xsi:nil="true"/>
<rsID xsi:nil="true"/><schArrival>08:12</schArrival><schDepart>08:13</schDepart><serviceAlertPresent>false</serviceAlertPresent>
<toc>SE</toc><tocName>Southeastern</tocName><trainID>1G65</trainID><trainLastReportedAt xsi:nil="true"/></getDestinationStationDashboardReturn>
<getDestinationStationDashboardReturn><RID>201309201386846</RID><alertDetailPopulated>false</alertDetailPopulated><alertsId>0</alertsId>
<alertsSummary xsi:nil="true"/><destExpArrival>10:08</destExpArrival><destSchArrival>10:08</destSchArrival><destinationStation>
<crsCode>BDM</crsCode><stationName>Bedford</stationName></destinationStation><expArrival>08:41</expArrival>
<expDepart>08:41</expDepart><otherAlertPresent>false</otherAlertPresent><platformNo>1</platformNo>
<routeDetailPopulated>false</routeDetailPopulated><routeDetails xsi:nil="true"/><rsID xsi:nil="true"/>
<schArrival>08:41</schArrival><schDepart>08:41</schDepart><serviceAlertPresent>false</serviceAlertPresent>
<toc>FC</toc><tocName>First Capital Connect</tocName><trainID>2W70</trainID><trainLastReportedAt>Train last reported at : Haywards Heath</trainLastReportedAt>
</getDestinationStationDashboardReturn><getDestinationStationDashboardReturn><RID>201309201377851</RID><alertDetailPopulated>false</alertDetailPopulated>
<alertsId>0</alertsId><alertsSummary xsi:nil="true"/><destExpArrival>08:24</destExpArrival><destSchArrival>08:24</destSchArrival><destinationStation>
<crsCode>BKL</crsCode><stationName>Bickley</stationName></destinationStation><expArrival>08:04</expArrival><expDepart>08:04</exp
```

Hope this will help you.

---

**The simplest way to parse Soap Response using the help of this class
Create a class name SoapResponseParser**

```
public class SoapResponseParser {


    public static void parseBusinessObject(String input, Object output)
            throws NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class theClass = output.getClass();
        Field[] fields = theClass.getDeclaredFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            Type type = fields[i].getType();
            fields[i].setAccessible(true);

            // detect String
            if (fields[i].getType().equals(String.class)) {
                String tag = fields[i].getName() + "=";

                if (input.contains(tag)) {
                    String strValue = input.substring(
                            input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if (strValue.length() != 0) {
                        if (strValue.contains("anyType")) {
                            fields[i].set(output, "-");
                        } else
                            fields[i].set(output, strValue);
                    }
                }
            }

            // detect int or Integer
            if (type.equals(Integer.TYPE) || type.equals(Integer.class)) {
                String tag = fields[i].getName() + "=";

                if (input.contains(tag)) {
                    String strValue = input.substring(
                            input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if (strValue.length() != 0) {
                        fields[i].setInt(output, Integer.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }

            // detect float or Float
            if (type.equals(Float.TYPE) || type.equals(Float.class)) {
                String tag = fields[i].getName() + "=";
                if (input.contains(tag)) {
                    String strValue = input.substring(
                            input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if (strValue.length() != 0) {
                        fields[i].setFloat(output, Float.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }
            // detect double or Double
            if (type.equals(Double.TYPE) || type.equals(Double.class)) {
                String tag = fields[i].getName() + "=";
                if (input.contains(tag)) {
                    String strValue = input.substring(
                            input.indexOf(tag) + tag.length(),
                            input.indexOf(";", input.indexOf(tag)));
                    if (strValue.length() != 0) {
                        fields[i].setDouble(output, Double.valueOf(strValue));
                    }
                }
            }
         }      
      }
}
```

---

**Edited doNetwork() method**

```
private void doNetwork() {
        SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi1.setName("crsCode");
        pi1.setValue("HNH");
        pi1.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        resultRequestSOAP.addProperty(pi1);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = true;
        try {
            envp.setOutputSoapObject(resultRequestSOAP);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(API_URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
            System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            System.out.println(androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envp.getResponse();
            GetDestinationStationDashboardReturn destination= new GetDestinationStationDashboardReturn();
            System.out.println("resultsString" + response.toString());
            SoapResponseParser.parseBusinessObject(response.toString(),
                    destination);
            System.out.println(destination.getRID()+"  "+destination.getAlertDetailPopulated()+" "+destination.getAlertsId());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

Now i explained how to parse, now its up to you how to achieve your requirement.
Happy Coding.

---

Create a Class GetDestinationStationDashboardReturn

```
public class GetDestinationStationDashboardReturn {
    private String RID;
    private String alertDetailPopulated;
    private String alertsId;
    private String destExpArrival;
    private String destSchArrival;
    public String getRID() {
        return RID;
    }
    public void setRID(String rID) {
        RID = rID;
    }
    public String getAlertDetailPopulated() {
        return alertDetailPopulated;
    }
    public void setAlertDetailPopulated(String alertDetailPopulated) {
        this.alertDetailPopulated = alertDetailPopulated;
    }
    public String getAlertsId() {
        return alertsId;
    }
    public void setAlertsId(String alertsId) {
        this.alertsId = alertsId;
    }
    public String getDestExpArrival() {
        return destExpArrival;
    }
    public void setDestExpArrival(String destExpArrival) {
        this.destExpArrival = destExpArrival;
    }
    public String getDestSchArrival() {
        return destSchArrival;
    }
    public void setDestSchArrival(String destSchArrival) {
        this.destSchArrival = destSchArrival;
    }

}
```

Comment: how to get these value crsCode , alertsId, destExpArrival

Comment: My problem is that how to get element value ?

Comment: @user2648752 First your problem while sending data using soap webservices. Now response is coming .. So now your problem is soap parsing.. It its helps for you so up vote my answer.

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37722/discussion-between-user2648752-and-amit-gupta)

Comment: what is this GetDestinationStationDashboardReturn  .Where is this class GetDestinationStationDashboardReturn

Comment: @user2648752 i forgot to add that class. plz see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 resultRequestSOAP     = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
 PropertyInfo UserName = new PropertyInfo();
 resultRequestSOAP.addProperty(UserName);
```

And if you want to add another parameter then you will have to create separate object of `PropertyInfo` like below :

```
 resultRequestSOAP      = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

 PropertyInfo UserName  = new PropertyInfo();
 PropertyInfo UserEmail = new PropertyInfo();

 resultRequestSOAP.addProperty(UserName);
 resultRequestSOAP.addProperty(UserEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use like this.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

   request.addProperty("crsCode","HNH");

   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.dotNet = true;
 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

  HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
  ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
  final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
 str = response.toString();
} 

  catch (Exception e) 
  {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

 Log.d("WebRespone", str);
 return str;
```

Hope this will help you. for your [reference](http://android-spirit.blogspot.in/2013/07/consume-net-webservice-in-android.html).

Comment: But how to get value from object

Comment: @user2648752 whats your parameter?can you post your parameter pls?Is it json or normal?

Comment: Now If I want to get RID and alertsSummary how I will get 
resultsStringanyType{RID=201309201377618; alertDetailPopulated=true; alertsId=0; alertsSummary=anyType{}; destExpArrival=06:31; destSchArrival=06:30; destinationStation=anyType{crsCode=BKJ; stationName=Beckenham Junction; }; expArrival=06:19; expDepart=06:20; otherAlertPresent=false; platformNo=3; routeDetailPopulated=false; routeDetails=null; rsID=null; schArrival=06:19; schDepart=06:19; serviceAlertPresent=false; toc=SE; tocName=Southeastern; trainID=2M06; trainLastReportedAt=null; }

Comment: @user2648752 then create class and assign those object in the class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://wsendpoints.bbrailapps.firstgroup.com/getDestinationStationDashboard";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getDestinationStationDashboard";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://wsendpoints.bbrailapps.firstgroup.com";
    private static final String URL = "http://railapps.firstgroup.com/FirstGroupRailApps/services/RailAppsCAWS?wsdl";
        SOAP_ACTION = SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        // Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("crsCode", HNS);
        String SoapResult = null;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
        SoapResult = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
    } else {
        SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapResult = resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();
    }

    Log.i(WebCalls, "Response " + SoapResult);
```

I hope its useful to you.